# alignment problem with safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, design

In this page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined

the first answer is aligned on the right of the page counter selector, shifting it out of flow. Safari 4.0.5. Under Firefox 3.5 the page looks fine.

Here is the shot [image]

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen.

Comment: @James : with the comment overlapping the Related section and the "wiki" word in community wiki overflowing the box (see the tab outline) ? I certainly don't think so.

Comment: I can't replicate it with Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed. Interesting, does not happen in Chrome which is also WebKit based.

I tend to assume that Safari and Chrome have basically the same rendering since they *do* use the same engine.

The only discrepancies in the past have been because Chrome has a more aggressive release/update schedule so tends to use newer builds of WebKit.